# Updating a table column with the 2nd oldest date in a row?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, sql-update, lateral-join

I would like to update the contents of the Date 1 column to reflect **2nd oldest** date each row. The table has thousands of rows and ~15 columns, only a handful of which are dates. I've used the least funtion in the past to update this column with the oldest date in each row, but I can't figure out how to update it with the 2nd oldest date(1/15/2020 for row 1 and 04/15/2020 for row 2 in this instance). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

| ID | Date 1 | Date 2 | Date 3 | Date 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 |  | 01/14/2020 | 01/15/2020 | 01/16/2020 |
| 002 |  | 04/15/2020 | 03/20/2020 | 06/16/2020 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest option might be to unpivot:

```
select t.*, d.date
from mytable t
cross join lateral (
    select date
    from (values (t.date2), (t.date3), (t.date4)) d(date)
    order by d.date
    limit 1 offset 1
) d
```

If you wanted an `update` statement:

```
update mytable t
set date1 = (
    select date
    from (values (date2), (date3), (date4)) d(date)
    order by d.date
    limit 1 offset 1
)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=694c9ccbeecbc111970de266532a635f)**

Comment: Thank you so much. The people who answer questions here are heroes.

Comment: What if I wanted to update the the Date 1 field with the oldest date in the row (update mytable
set date1 = least(date 2, date3, date4);
select * from mytable)
, but update Date 1 with the 2nd oldest only where the oldest date in the row has already passed (i.e. Date 1<currentdate)?

Comment: if it is preferred that I submit a new question, I can do this too.

Comment: @Tboi: yes, you might want to ask a new question for this.